# Cutting SELECT query time in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, query-optimization

I'm using CodeIgniter 2 and in my database model, I have a query that joins two tables and filters row based upon distance from a given geolocation.

```
SELECT users.id,
       (3959 * acos(cos(radians(42.327612)) *
          cos(radians(last_seen.lat)) * cos(radians(last_seen.lon) -
          radians(-77.661591)) + sin(radians(42.327612)) * 
          sin(radians(last_seen.lat)))) AS distance 
FROM users 
JOIN last_seen ON users.id = last_seen.seen_id 
WHERE users.age >= 18 AND users.age <= 30 
HAVING distance < 50
```

I'm not sure if it's the `distance` that is making this query take especially long. I do have over 300,000 rows in my `users table`. The same amount in my `last_seen` table. I'm sure that plays a role.

But, the `age` column in the users table is indexed along with the `id` column.
The `lat` and `lon` columns in the `last_seen` table are also indexed.

Does anyone have ideas as to why this query takes so long and how I can improve it?

**UPDATE**

It turns out that this query actually runs pretty quickly. When I execute this query in PHPMyAdmin, it takes 0.56 seconds. Not too bad. But, when I try to execute this query with a third party SQL client like SequelPro, it takes at least 20 seconds and all of the other apps on my mac slow down. When the query is executed by loading the script via jQuery's `load()` method, it takes around the same amount of time.

Upon viewing my network tab in Google Chrome's developer tools, it seems that the reason it's taking so long to load is because of what's called `TTFB` or Time To First Byte. It's taking forever.

[image: Developer tools screen shot]

Comment: Add the output of `explain select ...`

Comment: Indexes on lat and long won't help because you're doing calculations on them before filtering.

Comment: Is `last_seen.seen_id`  indexed?

Comment: Yes, `last_seen.seen_id` is indexed

Comment: By loose comparison, your calc runs in 0.1 seconds in a similar query I use to find the nearest 5 weather stations to users' locations.  12k weather stations and 250k users.  What's your run time?

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for each table.

Comment: When I execute this query in Sequel Pro (a desktop app for Mac that's a great alternative to PHPMyAdmin), it says that it takes 802 ms. However, it takes like 10 seconds for the rows to load. And all of my other active apps start to slow down.

Comment: There is no obvious reason for it to run 12-40 times as slow when using some extra layer.  Please focus on what that layer is doing.

Answer (score 1):

To make this query faster you need to limit the count of rows using an index before actually calculating the distance on every and each of them. To do so you can limit the rows from `last_seen` based on their lat/lon and a rough formula for desired distance.

The idea is that the positions with the same latitude as the reference latitude would be in 50 miles distance if their longitude falls in a certain distance from the reference longitude and vice versa.
For 50 miles distance, RefLat+-1 and RefLon+-1 would be a good start to limit the rows before actually calculating the precise distance.

```
last_seen.lat     BETWEEN 42.327612  - 1 AND  42.327612 + 1
AND last_seen.lon BETWEEN -77.661591 - 1 AND -77.661591 + 1
```

Answer (score 0):

For this query:

```
SELECT users.id, (3959 * acos(cos(radians(42.327612)) * cos(radians(last_seen.lat)) * cos(radians(last_seen.lon) - radians(-77.661591)) + sin(radians(42.327612)) * sin(radians(last_seen.lat)))) AS distance 
FROM users JOIN
     last_seen
     ON users.id = last_seen.seen_id 
WHERE users.age >= 18 AND users.age <= 30 
HAVING distance < 50;
```

The best index is `users(age, id)` and `last_seen(seen_id)`.  Unfortunately, the distance calculations are going to take a while, because they have to be calculated for every row.  You might want to consider a GIS extension to MySQL to help with this type of query.